# Knitr changes Image Size

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

When using RMarkdown + Knitr to make an HTML output of my code/plots, the plot images always appear as expected in RStudio with the correct width/height sizes specified in the chunk options, but if I then use Knitr to put everything together in an HTML document, the plots are all resized to a smaller default it seems.

Viewing each plot separately in a new tab shows their large size as desired but why can't this be the way they are shown in the HTML. Any setting I can change for this?

Comment: Will you proved an example .Rmd which others can use to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Peter Any code chunk with a plot significantly big will get resized when you Knit-r to HTML (and PDF). E.g. This code chunk plot is big when ran inline in rmarkdown but get's shrunk and turned into an HTML ```{r echo=FALSE, fig.width=14, fig.height=9}
 ggplot(mpg, aes(x=year, y=cyl))+geom_point()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `fig.width` and `out.width`, and likewise between `fig.height` and `out.height`.  The `fig.*` control the size of the graphic that is saved, and the `out.*` control how the image is scaled in the output.

For example, the following .Rmd file will produce the same graphic twice but displayed with different width and height.

````
---
title: "Example graphic"
---

```{r echo = FALSE, fig.width = 14, fig.height = 9, out.width = "588", out.height = "378"}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = year, y = cyl)) + geom_point()
```

```{r echo = FALSE, fig.width = 14, fig.height = 9, out.width = "1026", out.height = "528"}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = year, y = cyl)) + geom_point()
```
````

[image]

Comment: So `out.*` is in terms of pixels?

Comment: Default, yes, `out.*` are in pixels, However, you are not limited to pixels.  `out.height="40%"` is valid for html, `out.width = 0.48\\textwidth` is valid for LaTeX.  More details can be found on the [knitr options](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots).

Comment: Actually, I just retried this for an HTML output with `out.height` in pixels and it still caps the size of the images at a certain height/width. Even with a huge number of pixels, it seems to cap it.....